What is the minimum size of a choir to know that there must be at least 20 students in the choir from one of the schools?
I came across this permutations question on a year 12 exam this year.  Can someone please clarify how the answer is obtained. I don't follow what the examiner is saying.  The question is worth 1 mark.  By the way the answer is:
$$
19 \times 4 + 1 = 77
$$
Students from 4 different schools come together to form a choir.  What is the minimum size of a choir to know that there must be at least 20 students in the choir from one of the schools?

Since you need to know the minimum size, you are essentially concerned with the "worst" case scenario, where you don't select 20 people from one school until the last possible selection. With that said, you would be able to choose 19 students from each of the four schools without satisfying the criteria. Once you add one more, from either school, then there is a school with 20 students. 19 students from 4 schools is $4\cdot 19$, and adding one, of course, yields $4\cdot 19 +1$

@PotusOtis I think you can add that as an answer. It contains all the relevant details.

Why couldn't you just select 20 random people from the group of 4 schools and just fluke those 20 students from the 1 school.  Highly unlikely, but possible.

If we were randomly selecting students, there is a scenario where the first 20 students you choose are all from the same school. However, we are not randomly choosing while we are solving this problem. We are specifically selecting students from certain schools until we are forced to have 20 students from one school, hence my "worst case scenario" comment. Does that clear it up?

It will be helpful to read about the pigeonhole principle. (Questions like this are a straightforward generalisation of the most basic version of the pigeonhole principle)

Thanks SBK.  I can sort of see what the examiner is TRYING to convey.  Even though it does not specifically say that all 4 schools MUST be represented.

Since you need to know the minimum size, you are essentially concerned with the "worst" case scenario, where you don't select 20 people from one school until the last possible selection. With that said, you would be able to choose 19 students from each of the four schools without satisfying the criteria. Once you add one more student, from any of the schools, then there will be a school with 20 students.
19 students from 4 schools is $19\cdot4$, and adding that final student gets us:
$$19\cdot4+1=77$$
